# What is the symbol for a queue?

Tags: queue, diagram

In a flowchart or process diagram, what is the symbol for a FIFO queue?

Comment: Something like this --> "`Q`"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't have a source to cite, unfortunately, but I recall seeing it represented as an [isosceles trapezoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid).

Actually I found an example of it [here](http://cf.inspiration.com/download/pdf/V7SymbolGuide.pdf) (though maybe not the most authoritative of sources).

**Edit:** From comments it looks like the example site I had linked is no longer available. This is a recreation of what was in the original document:

[image: trapezoid]

Comment: The example link isn't responding but it's still viewable through the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090126224839/http://cf.inspiration.com/download/pdf/V7SymbolGuide.pdf). It's a trapezoid.

Comment: @SteveKehlet, thanks. I've edited to include the image.

Answer (score 64):

I don't know if this is canonical but, does this count?

[image]

Also here are examples of queues in SDL-88

http://www.sdl-forum.org/sdl88tutorial/4.ProcessCommunication/4.1_Signal_input_queue.htm

Comment: What software did you use to make this diagram? If it's a text file input based program (like plantuml, gnuplot, ditaa, graphviz, etc.) rather than a GUI like Visio, I'd really like to know.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky It looks like [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) (which uses XML-based [GraphML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML)).

Comment: This diagram is "Figure 64-1 Message Store Maintenance Queue" from "Communications Messaging Server System Administrator's Guide". Not sure what Oracle uses for their diagraming tools

Answer (score 58):

A stack is typically represented on a blackboard like this:

[image]

Reason being, you want the diagram to show "there's only 1 way in, one way out", and it's LIFO

For a queue, I would use something like this:

[image]

Shows there's both an entry and an exit, and that it is FIFO

Comment: If you're talking about an MQ queue (unlikely, but still...), the stack notation seems to be used regardless

Comment: I need to find a Visio library that has a shape just like this example.